# Prove that equation $A(y)= e^{\alpha x}$ has the particular solution

Tags: polynomials

Let $A$ a constant-coefficient operator with characteristic polynomial $P_A$.

If $\alpha$ is a simple of $P_A$ (multiplicity 1), prove that equation $A(y)= e^{\alpha x}$ has the particular solution
$$y_1 = \frac{xe^{\alpha x}}{P_{A_2} ^{\left( \alpha \right)}}$$. (This $P_ {A_2}$ would be P'_A, but there was a latex error)

Can someone give me some hint?

Comment: To show something is a solution, plug it in and calculate.  You should edit "a simple of" to "a simple root of".  I'm not sure what the superscript $(\alpha)$ is supposed to represent.

Comment: Should the equation read as $$y_1 = \frac{xe^{\alpha x}}{P_{A} '{\left( \alpha \right)}}?$$